# Проверка тип данных <PHP>

Tags: php, типы-данных

У меня на PHP приходят данные, и я пока не знаю какие.
Задача понять число ли это или нет. (int)
Проблема в том, что данные приходят в кавычках и если я уберу их, тип данных так и останется строковая.
Это всё на что мой мозг сейчас способен. 
Но у меня Warning на 11 строке, его хорошо бы убрать.
Подскажите метод, которым я могу это реализовать?

Заранее спасибо.

```
$str1 = "1";
$str2 = "бр";

$str1 = str_replace('"', '', $str1);
$str2 = str_replace('"', '', $str2);

$str1 += 0;
$str2 += 0;

if (is_int($str1)){ $q += 1;}
if (is_int($str2)){ $q += 1;}

echo $q.  ' ';
echo $str1.  ' ';
echo $str2.  ' ';
```

Comment: [Преобразование строк в числа](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). [Приведение типов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), [Функция settype()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.settype.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если числа могут быть только положительные, то ctype_digit();

```
$str1 = "1";
$str2 = "бр";

$str1 = ctype_digit($str1) ? intval($str1) : $str1;
$str2 = ctype_digit($str2) ? intval($str2) : $str2;

var_dump($str1, $str2);
```